# Is it safe to update the GPU drivers on this laptop?

Tags: drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, display-driver

I have an old [VAIO VPCCW1NFX/B Notebook](https://docs.sony.com/release//specs/VPCCW1NFXB_mksp.pdf) which comes with a NVIDIA GeForce GT 230M GPU.

Today when I wanted to use the [`Parallel Computing Toolbox 6.6`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/release-notes.html#R2015a) of MATLAB R2015a, I found that it's better to have the latest update of the display driver software.

Also I sometimes encounter [Display driver stopped responding and has recovered](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2665946) problem that I've found out one of it's causes can be outdated display driver software.

As [this page](https://esupport.sony.com/US/model-search/FR/model-home/template_id/1/region_id/1/template/EN/tab/download/mdl/VPCCW1NFXB#/downloadTab) suggests SONY does not support driver updates for this model anymore. And the currently installed driver version is

[image]

So I've decided to download and install [GeForce 341.92 Driver](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/94792/en-us) but the following paragraph in the "RELEASE HIGHLIGHTS" tab has scared me a bit:

> However, please note that your notebook original equipment
>   manufacturer (OEM) provides certified drivers for your specific
>   notebook on their website. NVIDIA recommends that you check with your
>   notebook OEM about recommended software updates for your notebook.
>   OEMs may not provide technical support for issues that arise from the
>   use of this driver

Is safe to upgrade the driver?

Comment: I have never had serious issues installing drivers directly from Nviida.

Comment: I think the "long shot/unlikely" risk comes from the possibility of the OEM altering the reference design. This used to happen on occasion in the 90s with (at my office, one or two Dell/Gateway), but I doubt it is much of a thing anymore.

Comment: In case you need to modify nVidias official driver to be able to install it on your machine, you can learn how to do this here:
http://forums.laptopvideo2go.com/topic/30969-modding-nvidia-oem-inf-files/
I had to do this myself once on an Acer TravelMate 8472TG. I had to modify "nvaci.inf" and "ListDevices.txt".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No big risk. If you have the Sony 259.57 driver at hand, you can try to install the latest nVidia-driver. If it doesn't work, you can go back to the Sony-driver (using safe mode if needed).

Answer (score 1):

341 drivers are very stable. I used 341.44 on a 425m for a long time.

Comment: Yes, I did the update and the problem "display driver has stopped working and is now being recovered" was solved